# Redbean ORDER BY

Tags: php, html, sql-order-by, redbean

Quick Question!

In redbean, seeing as you can order content like this with the findAll:

```
$all = R::findAll('needle',' ORDER BY title LIMIT 2 ');
```

It is possible to order a load function? I have tried but it doesn't work and the previous one does. This is what I tried:

```
$vals['events'][] = R::load('events', $eventid, ' ORDER BY title LIMIT 2 ');
```

Thanks!

Comment: `load` loads a single bean based on the `id`, so there is no reason to use the `ORDER BY` key words...  Unless you can tell me otherwise.

Comment: Well I think the difference here is that I am using the load function in a foreach loop. Sorry I forgot to mention that! `foreach ($eventinfo as $fd)
  {
   $eventid = $fd->id;
   $vals['events'][] = R::load('events', $eventid);
  }` Do you know how I can maybe order them?

Comment: Then your question should be about ordering your array of `$eventinfo` not about adding ORDER BY to the query.  And for that, you need to create a function using `usort()`

Comment: Apologies. I was unaware of being able to order the array. I will have to look into the function thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to update the events then loading the event is perfectly fine, if you just want to get the event information i would say use find which is better.

```
<?php 

$events = R::findAll('needle');
foreach($events as $e_info){
$eventid = $e_info->id;

$event_info = R::findOne('event_info', ' id = ?' , array($eventid));
//Do whatever you want with the data.
//You can also update it like
// $event_info->updated_at = R::isoDateTime();
//R::store($event_info);
}
?>
```

I hope this helps.